# Подключение библиотеки log4cxx

Tags: qt, c++, логирование

Хочу добавить в программу логирование с помощью log4cxx. Для начала решил написать пробную программу.

main.cpp

```
#include <log4cxx/logger.h>
#include <log4cxx/xml/domconfigurator.h>

using namespace log4cxx;
using namespace log4cxx::xml;
using namespace log4cxx::helpers;

LoggerPtr loggerMyMain(Logger::getLogger("main"));

int main() {
    DOMConfigurator::configure("Log4cxxConfig.xml");
    LOG4CXX_FATAL(loggerMyMain, "this is a fatal message!!!");
    return 0;
}
```

pro-файл

```
QT       += core

QT       -= gui

TARGET = untitled
CONFIG   += console
CONFIG   -= app_bundle

TEMPLATE = app

SOURCES += main.cpp

HEADERS += \
    log4cxx/logger.h \
    log4cxx/xml/domconfigurator.h
```

В итоге куча ошибок

```
debug/main.o: In function `main':
main.cpp:14: undefined reference to `log4cxx::xml::DOMConfigurator::configure(std::string const&)'
main.cpp:15: undefined reference to `log4cxx::Logger::isFatalEnabled() const'
main.cpp:15: undefined reference to `log4cxx::helpers::MessageBuffer::MessageBuffer()'
main.cpp:15: undefined reference to `log4cxx::spi::LocationInfo::LocationInfo(char const*, char const*, int)'
main.cpp:15: undefined reference to `log4cxx::helpers::MessageBuffer::operator<<(char const*)'
main.cpp:15: undefined reference to log4cxx::helpers::MessageBuffer::str(log4cxx::helpers::CharMessageBuffer&)'  
main.cpp:15: undefined reference to `log4cxx::Level::getFatal()'
main.cpp:15: undefined reference to log4cxx::Logger::forcedLog(log4cxx::helpers::ObjectPtrT<log4cxx::Level> const&, std::string const&, log4cxx::spi::LocationInfo const&) const'
main.cpp:15: undefined reference to `log4cxx::helpers::MessageBuffer::~MessageBuffer()'
debug/main.o: In function `_static_initialization_and_destruction_0':
main.cpp:9: undefined reference to `log4cxx::Logger::getLogger(char const*)'
debug/main.o: In function `~ObjectPtrT':
log4cxx/helpers/objectptr.h:100: undefined reference to log4cxx::helpers::ObjectPtrBase::~ObjectPtrBase()'
log4cxx/helpers/objectptr.h:100: more undefined references to log4cxx::helpers::ObjectPtrBase::~ObjectPtrBase()' follow
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
mingw32-make.exe[1]: *** [debug\untitled.exe] Error 1
mingw32-make.exe: *** [debug] Error 2
```

Comment: Вы не подключили соответствующую статическую библиотеку.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Похоже, вы недоподключили кое-какие исходники библиотеки Log4cxx, а также бинарные модули (*.lib). [Здесь](http://habrahabr.ru/post/118003/#habracut) подробно все описано. Не обращайте внимание, что для Visual Studio, т.к. вам нужно только понять, чего не достает в вашем проекте.

Comment: проблема в том что именно не подключено не могу понять.

Comment: Похоже, нужны заголовочные файлы. Компилятор не может разрешить символ - это значит, ему неоткуда взять его определение (definition). 

Посмотрите эту статью - там есть пример подключения заголовочных файлов - их там чуть ли не с десяток.

Comment: @vladimir_ki `undefined reference` в `gcc` - это ошибка этапа линковки, а не компиляции. То есть, хэдеры подключены правильно, а вот статической библиотеки `logcxx` не хватает.

Comment: @Котик_хочет_кушать, вы правы. На это отличие от MSVC я не обратил внимание.

Comment: библиотеку подключил.
    LIBS += -L$$PWD/ -llog4cxx
    INCLUDEPATH += $$PWD/log4cxx
    DEPENDPATH += $$PWD/log4cxx
ошибка осталась...

Comment: вы сами собирали log4cxx? Компилятор gcc? Какие настройки компилятора использовались?

Answer (score 1):

Используй log4qt - все будет просто и эффективно. Есть куча примеров по нему.
[Пример инициализации и использования log4qt](http://log4qt.sourceforge.net/html/init.html)

Comment: необходимо использовать именно log4cxx